# copy files from one location to another in powershell script, in addition checking for certain values

Tags: file, powershell, directory

So I have folder with files in it, in a certain location

```
C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\testfiles
```

so I want to move those files to this location

```
C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\destinationTestfiles
```

the "testfiles" have files of this format `txt.*.test.*` so basically I wanna check before I move the files that they have those two main stuff (`txt`) and (`test`) in the third part.

can someone help me,  how can perform this in powershell script

I know I can do this, to set the folders paths

```
path_src= C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\testfiles
path_dst= C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\destinationTestfiles
```

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: ".. ...  in the third part." what's the third part? Are you saying the the FILENAMES are `txt.(something).test.(something)`? Or is the content inside that's like this? If it's the filenames: is the last `(something)` the extension or is it `txt.(something).test.(something).extension`?

Comment: txt.(something).test.(something).extension
it could end up with anything, after second something it could be date then extension format, there no specific thing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there are no subfolders in testfiles(at least that you need files from), try this:

```
$src = "C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\testfiles"
$dst = "C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\destinationTestfiles"

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "txt.*.test.*" | Move-Item -Destination $dst -Force
```

If you have files in subfolders of the source-path, try this:

```
$src = "C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\testfiles"
$dst = "C:\Users\ainfowara\Desktop\destinationTestfiles"

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "txt.*.test.*" -Recurse | % {
    #Creates an empty file at the destination to make sure that subfolders exists
    New-Item -Path $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -ItemType File -Force
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -Force
}
```

Be aware that if your filename contains square-bracket `[ ]` you need another script (known PS bug).

Comment: this gave me errors, it created empty files for the subfolders but never changed them to folders and copied over the folder contents. this worked instead: ```$sourceRoot = "C:\temp"
$destinationRoot = "C:\n"

Copy-Item -Path $sourceRoot -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -Destination $destinationRoot -Container```